# Using ImageView in ScrollView without blank

Tags: android, imageview, scrollview

I want to add pictures in scrollview. My code below. There are two images. And I do not want to display blank image in them. I will use about 10 images. How I can do?

It displays like this---->

[image]

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView 

     android:id="@+id/mat1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:src="@drawable/mata"
     />

     <ImageView 

      android:layout_below="@+id/mat1"
      android:id="@+id/mat2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:src="@drawable/matb"
      />        

 </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: This question lacks in clarity. Please tell us what is happening now (with image) and what are you expecting (with image), for good answers

Comment: quite unclear question, please ellaboate it in detail proper.

Comment: Not getting you. Can you please Elaborate?

Comment: i can't add picture. I have no enough reputation. My question is that i want to image in scrollview. It works. But it has blank among image.   http://i.imgur.com/Kiv9FHC.png?1

Comment: i still can't run correctly. It has blanks.